# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE replace space in middle with empty string

Tags: regex, string, oracle, regexp-replace

I'm trying to use the Oracle `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to replace a whitespace (which is in the middle of a string) with an empty string.

One of my columns contains strings like the following one.

- *[alphanumeric][space][digits][space][alpha]* (eg. `R4SX 315 GFX`)

Now, I need to replace ONLY the second whitespace (the whitespace after the digits) with an empty string (i.e. `R4SX 315 GFX` --> `R4SX 315GFX`)

To achieve this, I tried the following code:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
   'R4SX 315 GFX', 
   '([:alphanum:])\s(\d)\s([:alpha:])', 
   '\1 \2\3') "REPLACED" 
FROM dual;
```

However, the result that I get is the same as my input (i.e. `R4SX 315 GFX`).
Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong and please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be `alnum`, not `alphanum`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I tried that before posting this question. Still the same result. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [:alphanum:]

`alphanum` is incorrrect. The alphanumeric character class is **`[[:alnum:]]`**.

You could use the following **pattern** in the **REGEXP_REPLACE**:

```
([[:alnum:]]{4})([[:space:]]{1})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:space:]]{1})([[:alpha:]]{3})
```

Using **REGEXP**

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('R4SX 315 GFX',
  2                        '([[:alnum:]]{4})([[:space:]]{1})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:space:]]{1})([[:alpha:]]{3})',
  3                        '\1\2\3\5')
  4  FROM DUAL;

REGEXP_REPL
-----------
R4SX 315GFX

SQL>
```

If you are not sure about the number of characters in each expression of the pattern, then you could do:

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('R4SX 315 GFX',
  2                        '([[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)',
  3                        '\1\2')
  4  FROM dual;

REGEXP_REPL
-----------
R4SX 315GFX

SQL>
```

Using **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**

The same could be done with substr and instr which wouldbe less resource consuming than regexp.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 'R4SX 315 GFX' str FROM DUAL
  3    )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, ' ', 1, 2) -1)
  5    ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, ' ', 1, 2)       +1, LENGTH(str)-instr(str, ' ', 1, 2)) new_str
  6  FROM DATA;

NEW_STR
-----------
R4SX 315GFX

SQL>
```

Comment: @Asela You're welcome! I have added another example using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex contains an invalid class `alphanum`. Also, these classes must be used inside character classes `[...]`. Instead of `\s`, you need to use a supported `[:blank:]` class. More details on the regex syntax in MySQL can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

I recommend using

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
 'R4SX 315 GFX', 
 '([[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)'
 , '\1\2') "REGEXP_REPLACE" 
FROM dual;
```

This way you will use just 2 capturing groups. The less we have the better is for performance. Here you can see more details on [REGEXP_REPLACE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).